# Customer email is required pay via PayPal Express Checkout error

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

Getting an error 'Customer email is required' when clicking on the Place Order button while checking out using the guest account.

Check this link: 
https://www.nextdaygames.com/gran-turismo-sport-playstation-4

Click on Buy Now Button->Pay with a sandbox account with PayPal->Place Order from review page. Check Attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did this get resolved? I am having the same issue (seems I cannot comment until I have 50 reputation points)

Mostly seems to be from Apple devices and/or mobile devices when trying to place an order as a guest

Only change I have made recently was to upgrade onestepcheckout to the latest version. I have mentioned it to the developer in the hopes its related however I get an email titled "Payment Transaction Failed Reminder" and in the email the checkout type listed is Onepage, not onestepcheckout

No errors in logs. Magento version 1.9.3.7

Comment: Yes. I have resolved this. I have performed so many steps to resolve this. Currently i can't say that this step was solved my issue. But I solved this one. You can checkout above link with test sandbox skype account.

Comment: you are unable to comment then write to pilukamani@gmaildotcom